# Where are the savegames located in x-com enemy unknown?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I have a lot of savegames and I'd like to clean them up. Ingame you can only delete them one by one. There is a folder "Saves" in the steamapps folder (I have the steam game) but there are no files in there.
Am I looking at the wrong location?

I am currently even facing problems. Not all savegames are offered in the menu - probably because I have so many.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On windows 7, they are in `Documents\My Games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData`

Note that this applies to the steam install.  According to helpful comments, it's the location is the same for the retail version (and retail purchases apparently just provide steam keys).

Comment: I'm pretty sure XCOM is a Steamworks game, which means there's *only* a steam version - the retail version comes with a code and disc that must be activated with Steam in order to work.

Comment: Ah, so the Saves folder in steamapps is just to confuse me :).

Comment: @StampedeXV - yeah, more or less.  ;)

Comment: I can confirm that savegames of the retail version are saved at the same position as the digital download one.

Answer (score 10):

On MacOS, the Steam edition saves its games to `~/Library/Application Support/Feral Interactive/XCOM Enemy Unknown/SaveData/`. I suspect the non-Steam version is the same (aka Elite Edition, Mac AppStore). Details from [this blog post](http://myglasseye.net/news/xcom-mac-sync-saved-games-dropbox/). The Steam edition also has [Steam Cloud synchronization](http://steamcommunity.com/app/200510/discussions/0/846959876021207912/), but I have not verified that it's working.

XCOM Enemy Within saves its games in `~/Library/Application Support/Feral Interactive/XCOM Enemy Unknown/XEW/SaveData`.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned here: https://steamcommunity.com/app/200510/discussions/0/522730699423954666/

Here is the location of the save game for Linux

> ~/.local/share/feral-interactive/XCOM/ for Enemy Unknown and
>
> ~/.local/share/feral-interactive/XCOM/XEW/ for Enemy Within
>
> Saves are in the savedata/ folder in XCOM/ or XCOM/XEW/.

Hope this helps some future googlers!

Comment: thanks for completing this. I bet there's a few looking for this.

Answer (score -2):

Steam Version on Windows 7:

```
Users\[USERNAME]\Documents\My Games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData
```

Comment: This answer isn't wrong. It is just the same as the accepted one.

Answer (score -3):

It's the 'users' folder, even if you've moved your normal documents - it still goes to the Windows default folder...