# Is there a solution to Xcom - Enemy Unknown save game bug?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I deleted some save games from within the the game and now it seems that I cannot save games anymore, only on rare occasions when a new mission begins. Also a new game that I started does not get saved.

Is there a solution which does not involve re-installing?

Comment: Is this about the PC version of the game?

Comment: Jip, the PC/Steam version

Comment: bug is described here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgaWvwd9GMo

Comment: I've tried deleting all the saved game files out of game. Relaunching the game, all the saved games still appear however in the list however trying to launch one gives an error dialogue. This indicates that there is a secret database storing info about the save games, which is not in that SaveData folder.

Comment: did you delete that many that the number of saves came under 90? until you come below, nothing will change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution here: [Link to 2k-forums](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?154871-Save-game-bug-Sudden-loss-of-save-games), at least for my problem.

Xcom seems to have problems handling to many save games. So, go into your [save game folder](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89177/where-are-the-savegames-located-in-x-com-enemy-unknown) (e.g.: "C:\Users\\Documents\my games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData") and delete or move old save games. Et Viola!

Comment: deleteing old saves only worked for some time, then it got all screwed up...

Comment: so whats the deal now?

Answer (score 7):

The other answers miss out on a few details that can still cause issues.

The resolution to most of the save game bugs in X-Com: Enemy Unknown lie with the file profile.bin, and what the game tries to do when it thinks there is something wrong.  Some of the self-repair features can kick in and recreate the problem if you do not follow all of the following steps.

With the game turned off, open the save game location (C:\Users\%username%\Documents\my games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData by default)

Copy any files you wish to keep to a different folder.

Delete the entire folder.

Start X-Com.

Once the game reaches the main menu, it will briefly say "Loading Profile".

At this point, you can copy the files you moved earlier back into the save game folder.

Bypassing any of these steps can cause issues.  If the save game folder is deleted, though, the game starts from scratch, creating a brand new profile.bin and SaveData folder instead of trying to recreate it with data from Steam and other hidden files.  Any old saves dropped into the folder will be read and added to the new profile, and any new saves will work as normal--until you reach 90+ saves again, that is.  It is a particularly frustrating bug because it is easy to seemingly fix the game and have it come back a launch or two later.

Comment: Very good! The important part is not to move the saves to a subdirectory of `savedata`, because it seems XCOM will still index them there even if you delete `profile.bin`. So renaming the folder and copying just few last saves works!

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot! Also it's important to move back just a few saves otherwise the bug will return.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the savegame folder (`C:\Users\%username%\Documents\my games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData`), copy your latest saves to a new folder elsewhere, delete every thing in the save folder, and start the game.

If you look at the saves, they should all be blank. Exit the game, copy your saves back to the `SaveData` folder, and restart the game.