# How to delete my XCom Saves?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

So first a confession: I was playing iron man, but I would cheat in that at the beginning of every month I would make a backup of the game.  Then near the end of the month I would restore the game, or re-save depending how I did for the month.

In doing all this I totally messed up my save menu.  Half the games will not load anymore, because the file is not there anymore.  But more importantly is that I can't delete the games from the in-game menu.  When I try to delete it just goes back to the top of the list.

My concern is I saw a youtube video about if you have too many saves the game will no longer save.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this issue, short of a re-install?

Comment: I'm also interested in this, although for a different reason. If you have saves in multiple languages, it gives you an annoying popup every time you try to load a game saying "Games from other languages can't be loaded." I'd like to delete all my save games in one language in order to get rid of that popup, then exclusively play in the other language.

Comment: Basically you are asking "How can I cheat without problems?"

Comment: @Sjoerd The context of what he's asking is largely irrelevant. The question of how to delete saves is still completely legitimate. Additionally, as a single-player game, what do you care how he plays? If he wants to savescum his ironman game because that's fun for him, it doesn't affect you at all.

Comment: Have you tried overwriting those saves, meaning making the new saves on the spots of the old saves.

Comment: no, because I was in ironman mode, but I guess I can create a new game and try that.  Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Look in the save game folder. Folder location is detailed in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89177/where-are-the-savegames-located-in-x-com-enemy-unknown)

Comment: I know where they are I deleted or overwritten most of them.  The issue is deleting them from the in-game menu.  I have yet to try Ilya suggestion.

Comment: @peakxu That folder contains a **profile.bin**, which most likely contains a list of saved games. If that file wasn't copied along the save game, I guess the OP is out of luck. Hopefully, removing all files from the save folder might work, but if not, a full reinstall seems the only option.

Comment: interesting note... deleting the profile.bin or re-installing the game help.  Now when I re-installed I selected Delete Local Content and had it install from previous downloaded files.  Not sure why this did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XCOM saves are kept in:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData
```

So, I would assume that deleting all of the save files in that folder would delete all your save games. But make a backup of the folder in case so you can put it back to how it was if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

I posed the same question:

more or less a duplicate of: [Where are the savegames located in x-com enemy unknown?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89177/where-are-the-savegames-located-in-x-com-enemy-unknown)

The games are saved in
Documents\My Games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData

And deleting them works fine. I always deleted all savegames older than a few days so kept my latest ones. Never had any trouble with it.

The list of savegames was refreshed ingame after the next restart. (btw: I always deleted them when the game was not started to avoid any unwanted side effects).

Comment: My question is not about where the games are located.  It has to do with the ingame menu-- I delete the actual files, now I can not delete the games that come up when you choose load/save game.  How did you remove them from the game menu after removing the local file?

Comment: They were gone after a restart of the game. To me it seemed it was using only the files on disk to decide which savegames are there.

Comment: In my case when I restarted it synced them back from the steam cloud (!). In the end I deleted them all in-game instead. Deleting them from disk when the game is started seems to work too.

Answer (score 2):

I got XCOM Enemy Within and Enemy Unknown at the same time through Steam, and I believe this pattern works for both. It also works with XCOM2. The other answers didn't work for me because Steam kept recreating the files. The saved games are in `C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\My Games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData` as above. **Back up** your entire SaveData directory before starting! I've also used this with Enemy Within.

1. Delete nothing from SaveData. If you want to save any games, copy them out and renumber them save1, save2, etc.
2. Start XCOM, online and connected to steam.
3. Get in windowed mode if you aren't already, or just use Windows-D to show your desktop.
4. Delete the `SaveData` folder.
5. Go back to the running XCOM, online and connected to steam.
6. Exit to desktop.
7. Start XCOM, online and connected to steam.
8. Copy in your save game files.
9. Restart XCOM. Your selected save files should be there. If you do see one with an error (something about a mismatch) that one won't work, and will crash XCOM. You probably thought that one was your last save, but it may not be.

Alternate method, tested with XCOM 2. There's a little less manual effort in this one.

1. Back up your `SaveData` folder.
2. Start XCOM, online and connected to steam.
3. Get in windowed mode if you aren't already, or just use Windows-D to show your desktop.
4. Delete the save files you don't want to keep from the `SaveData` folder.
5. Go back to the running XCOM, online and connected to steam.
6. Exit XCOM to desktop.
7. Restart XCOM. You now have just the files you left. No renumbering of save files are needed (at least for XCOM 2).

Answer (score 1):

Move the subfolder you're saving your games to out of the saved games folder. The next time it loads, everything will be fine.

Comment: If you use a shortcut to a folder rather than a real folder, that works too.