# Transferring a Slime Rancher save

Tags: macos, slime-rancher

I would like to transfer Slime Rancher saves to a new computer, without the use of Steam.

I am using macOS Sierra.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Do you play that game via Steam or is it directly installed on your computer ?

Comment: Steam and direct install.

Comment: Well usually on Windows the save files are in C:\Users\YourName\Documents\My Games .
But when switching computer maybe the saves files won't be at the same place. So first you need to find the saves on the PC you're using now,then you launch your game on the new one like that he will create new saves in the right directory. And then you just have to find that directory and paste your old saves while deleting the ones just created.

Comment: @Ise I should've clarified that this is macOS and not Windows.

Comment: Ah yes you totally should have cause it's totally not the same.

Comment: But with a little search you will then have found it here : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89177/where-are-the-savegames-located-in-x-com-enemy-unknown/127218?s=5|0.1067#127218

Comment: @Ise we don't close questions as dupes unless the question itself is a duplicate. Duplicate answers do not make the question a dupe.

Comment: @Vemonus Ok thanks I'll keep that in mind from now :)

Comment: Seriously? I'm getting downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

On **OSX** :

- Right click on the game in your library
- Click on properties
- Click on local files
- The finder window will take you to : library/support/steam/steamapps/common/[gameName]
- Back track to application support and you'll find another folder of your game where the save is

In the **Terminal** :

- cd ~/Library/Application Support/

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/48700/discussions/0/45350791664189606/?l=french)